# This code runs and compiles but nothing happens when I enter a very large number. (Euler project, problem 3)

Tags: java

I'm a newbie.

So I've been doing the project Euler problems to sharpen my java skills and I got past the first 2. I'm stuck on the third one. It says :

"The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?"

I wrote the following code:

```
public class Exercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long a = 600851475143L;
        long i = 1;
        boolean isPrime = true;
        long currentNum = 0;
        while (i <= a) {
            if (a % i == 0) {
                for (long j = 1; j < a; j++) {
                    if (a == i || a % j == 0) {
                        isPrime = false;
                    } else {
                        currentNum = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("the largest prime factor of " + a + " is " + currentNum);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly for smaller numbers like 10,20,55,100,560523 etc but when I enter a large number like 600851475143L, the code compiles and runs but nothing happens.

Any help appreciated, thanks !

Comment: the range for long datatype is –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9 ,223,372,036,854,775,807. so it should work fine. show your errors or stacktraces

Comment: "Nothing happens" - means your code is stuck and doesn't return to prompt, or that it returns to prompt immediately?

Comment: You are running through over 600 billion numbers, and for each number, you are running through that many numbers again. That will take a really long time to get through. You should look at ways to optimize your algorithm.

Comment: A couple of hints: no factor of N will be greater than the square root of N. Also, you are looking for the biggest one, so start from the square root of N and go downwards. You have a `isPrime` flag but you are not doing anything with it. You should stop when it's prime. You should stop the inner loop when it's not prime.

Comment: Just as an estimate: Let's say each iteration of the loop takes 1 nanosecond. Your loop will iterate 600 * 600 = 360 trillion times, which will take 360 trillion nanoseconds to complete. That translates to about 100 hours of running time.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Is that really true ? Square root of 36 is 6, but 12 is a factor of 36 and it's greater than 6. Or maybe you meant something else ? I didn't know about the isPrime() method, thanks

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I'll qualify that: for prime testing, you never need to go beyond the square root, because all the multipliers you check beyond that are complementary to ones you have already checked. (if 15 divides by 3, there is no point in checking if it divides by 5). For factoring, you need to go only up to the square root, but you need to check each prime factor you find to find its complementary (E.g., for 20, you reach 2, you divide 20 by 2 = 10, not prime. Divide again by 2 = 5. Prime. So it's the biggest you have so far - without going all the way through 3 and 4).

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks !! I'll try that and see if it is any faster !  Say I'm going for a number which is as big as the square of 600billion(the one that I'm supposed to find out the biggest prime factor of) then, wouldn't this way of looking for complementary numbers take just as long ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested conditions, executions of which will hop CPU.

```
while (i <= a) {// This condition will be executed 600851475143 times
                if (a % i == 0) {
                    for (long j = 1; j < a; j++) {// This condition will be executed 600851475143 times
```

So far a=600851475143, code will execute `600851475143*600851475143` times. That's why you don't see output as CPU is busy executing so many conditions.

Also reason you saw output for a=100 because for this input number of iterations = `100*100` which won't take much time on any modern machine

Answer (score 4):

Look at your `a` variable. It's `600851475143L`. 
That means that your processor has to do up to 600851475143 loop cycles, based on your condition:

```
while (i <= a) {
    i++;
}
```

I do not take into consideration the code inside the `while()` loop, but even without it that is too much, even for modern computers :)

If you want to calculate prime factors of numbers of that range... you should consider using some more efficient ways than simple iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Exercise  {
    public static void main(String[] r)
       {
        try{
        long a = 600851475143L; 
        System.out.println("the largest prime factor of " + a+ " is " +largestPrimeFactor(a) );
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

    public static int largestPrimeFactor(long number) {
        int i;
        long copyOfInput = number;

        for (i = 2; i <= copyOfInput; i++) {
            if (copyOfInput % i == 0) {
                copyOfInput /= i;
                i--;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Pavel Smirnov is correct. Actually, the code **is** running for value `600851475143L` as well. It's just that the input number is huge so the code is taking hell lot of time to finish. Even the code is not in the deadlocked state.  Still, to prove the point to you, you can add a log in the inner-loop body like:

`System.out.println("Testing Prime for Number :"+j);`

in the inner-loop `for (long j = 1; j < a; j++){}`

Doing this, you will see that the code is actually running.

P.S.: This algorithm will loop `600851475143L * 600851475143L` times, which is really time-consuming.